# Problem changing the TextMeshPro UI text within a canvas using a script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem changing the scoring values using TextMeshPro in a canvas from a script within the canvas. I'm getting a NullPointerException error because i feel that i am not referencing the score text files correctly but im not sure how to do it correclty. 
**Error** :

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   Score.PlayerOneScored () (at Assets/Scripts/Score.cs:20)

**Code** :

```
public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
static int scoreValue1 = 0;
static int scoreValue2 = 0;
private TMP_Text score1;
private TMP_Text score2;

public void PlayerOneScored() {
    Debug.Log("Player One Scored");
    scoreValue1++;

    TMP_Text score1 = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
    Debug.Log("P1 Score: " + scoreValue1);
    score1.text = "Score: " + scoreValue1;
    }

public void PlayerTwoScored()
{
    Debug.Log("Player Two Scored");
    scoreValue2++;

    TMP_Text score2 = GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
    Debug.Log("P2 Score: " + scoreValue2);
    score2.text = "Score: " + scoreValue2;
    }
}
```

Line 20 is

```
score1.text = "Score: " + scoreValue1;
```

Picture of the Hierarchy :
[ScoreCanvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFrDg.png)

**Update** Have it working now! This was my class in the end

```
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;
   using UnityEngine.UI;
   using TMPro;

   public class Score : MonoBehaviour
   {
   static int scoreValue1 = 0;
   static int scoreValue2 = 0;
   public TextMeshProUGUI score1;
   public TextMeshProUGUI score2;


void Awake()
{
    score1.text = "Score: " + scoreValue1;
    score2.text = "Score: " + scoreValue2;
}


public void PlayerOneScored() {

    if (scoreValue1 < 10) {
        scoreValue1++;
        Debug.Log("Player One Scored");
        Debug.Log("P1 Score: " + scoreValue1);

        score1.text = "Score: " + scoreValue1;
    }
    else { }
}

public void PlayerTwoScored()
{
    if (scoreValue2 < 10)
    {
        scoreValue2++;
        Debug.Log("Player Two Scored");
        Debug.Log("P2 Score: " + scoreValue2);

        score2.text = "Score: " + scoreValue2;
    }
    else { }
}
}
```

Comment: I doubt that actually .. I'ld go with Draco18s: The `score1` is `null` since `GetComponent` fails .. are you sure this script is on the correct GameObject, the same which also has a `TextMeshProUGui` component? There is nothing else in that method which can possibly throw this exception .. which could easily see by debugging with breakpoints so I'ld say it is a duplicate. In the other one you are also using `TMP_Text` .. maybe you should use it in the first one as well?

Comment: If this is no duplicate in your opinion please argue what exactly you tried / didn't understand from the duplicate thread.

Comment: @derHugo The Score script is attached to the ScoreCanvas, where both the Text files are attached. I read through the link and many other pages and i cannot understand in my case what i'm doing wrong, i'm a begineer at unity and have a heavy workload with other subjects so i wanted to ask you hoping ye wouldnt shut my thread down again because i cant understand what i'm doing wrong. The duplicate thread is very very broad and i can't find where it can help me. I'm dumb basically. Thats why i wanted help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comment you said your script is attached to the `Canvas` GameObject.

**But** you are using

```
GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
```

Note that [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html)

> Returns the component of Type type if the game object has one attached, **`null` if it doesn't.**

It only returns Components attached to the very **same** `GameObject`. In your description this is **not the case**. The Components you are trying to get are on **child** GameObjects of your `Canvas`!

---

Now **if** there would be **only one** you **could** use another variant like `GetComponentInChildren` ... **BUT**: since in your case you have two different ones and want to be able to differ between them you can't use it .. it would always return the same reference.

---

There are multiple possible solutions but here is what I would do: Simply remove both `GetComponent` lines completely and rather set your references via the Unity Inspector! This can be done by either make a field `public` or use [`[SerializeField]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) on a `private` one:

```
// Now both these fields will appear in the Inspector
// so you can simply drag&drop the according GameObjects into the slots
[SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI score1;
public TextMeshProUGUI score2;
```

---

Another option would be to get the according child objects on runtime (this is more error prone ofcourse)

```
score1 = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponemt<TextMeshProUGUI>();

...

score2 = transform.GetChild(1). GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
```

Comment: Thanks so much! So i changed that to public and assigned it  (i had tried this before but now i see 
i was overriding it with the GetComponent so i deleted that). My only problem now is that fact that for my game, the scene resets each time a player scores, therefore reseting the text (but not the values of score). So i see that the score has changed and then it immediately changes back to the deafult value. How would i go about keeping the written string across the reset for the scene?

Comment: Never mind, got it working. Will put in update what i did. Thank you!